# Create a recursive sorted list of files (by oldest first)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a recursive list of files from a directory, and then sort them based on age.  I dont really care too much about file extension, just the oldest file first.

here is what I have so far, but it isnt sorting by date...

ex:
    /home/user/folder/dir1
    /home/user/folder/dir2
    /home/user/folder/dir3

```
def returnold():
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(imagedir):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.jpg, *.png'):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return sorted(matches, key=lambda p: os.path.getctime(os.path.join(user_dir, p)))

imagedir = /home/user/folder
filelist = returnold()
```

Honestly, my goal here is to process all the files under home/user/folder, the oldest file first. Rather than process all the files in dir1/ first, then dir2/ next, I need to process the oldest file first, regardless where it exists in that tree structure. My thought was that I could write a while list is not empty loop to process all the files.  If there is a better way, I would love to learn.  Appreciate any help you could add here.

Comment: How is it sorting it? It doesn't look like there is an error (but I have never heard of `fnmatch` before).

Comment: `ctime` is not creation time. It is the time of the last inode change. Unfortunately there isn't a guaranteeable way to get the actual age of a file, but you can use `mtime` to get the age of the file since the last *modification*.

Answer (score 4):

I think I figured it out..

```
import os
import fnmatch

def returnold(folder):
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folder):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.*'):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return sorted(matches, key=os.path.getmtime)

nextimage = returnold('/path/to/folder')
```

This will return a sorted list by file modified date, nextimage[0] being the oldest, nextimage[-1] being the newest. Alternatively, if you just want to return the oldest file (and not a sorted list), you can just return the min of the list, like so:

```
def returnold(folder):
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folder):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.*'):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return min(matches, key=os.path.getmtime)


nextimage = returnold('/path/to/folder')
```